# accessing variable in terragrunt that is in terraform.tfvars

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I have this `terraform.tfvars` file in the following location:

```
root
|_prod
  |_eu-west-2
    |_dev
      |_terraform.tfvars
      |_cognito
        |_terragrunt.hcl
```

it has these values:

```
terragrunt = {
  terraform {
    extra_arguments "custom_vars" {
      commands = [
        "apply",
        "plan",
        "import",
        "push",
        "refresh"
      ]

      # With the get_tfvars_dir() function, you can use relative paths!
      arguments = [
        "-var-file=terraform.tfvars"
      ]
    }
  }
}

reply_to_email_address = "blah.blah@blah.scot"
```

I can't find in the docs how to access this.  I've tried `get_env`:

```
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

terraform {
  // double `//` before module are important!
  source = "../../../../../terraform-modules//cognito"
}

inputs = {
  name                    = "pvg-online-${local.env}"
  reply_to_email_address  = get_env("reply_to_email_address", "")
}
```

But it gets set to the default `""`

Answer (score 6):

This is actually such a common use case that terragrunt has built-in functionality for it.

In your `terragrunt.hcl`, include a `terraform{}` block like the following:

```
terraform {
  # Note that the double-slash (//) syntax is not needed for local relative paths
  source = "../../../../../terraform-modules/cognito"

  extra_arguments "common_var" {
    commands  = get_terraform_commands_that_need_vars()
    arguments = ["-var-file=${get_terragrunt_dir()}/../terraform.tfvars"]
  }
}

inputs = {
  name = "pvg-online-${local.env}"
  # Since reply_to_email_address is provided in the parent terraform.tfvars file,
  # it is not needed as an input
}
```

Note the use of [`get_terraform_commands_that_need_vars()`](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/built-in-functions/#get_terraform_commands_that_need_vars) so you can avoid listing out all the arguments, as well as [`get_terragrunt_dir()`](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/built-in-functions/#get_terragrunt_dir) for finding the directory of `terragrunt.hcl`.